# Trouble appending d3 vectors to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I'm trying to get points to overlay on a leaflet map.

I create the Map element in html, build the leaflet map, read in the data.

Here's where I'm getting tripped up.  I'd like to display points on the map - I've already successfully displayed these points on a d3 map, but I want to re-display them on the above leaflet map.  Rather then extract lat/longs, as I've seen in d3 + leaflet examples, I thought I'd just use the path generator function which I've used successfully before, in order to append points to leaflet.

Code sequence here:

```
    <div id="map" class="sf" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

     function ready(error) {

         //Build Leaflet map
         L.mapbox.accessToken = 

'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RhcnJtb3NzMSIsImEiOiJjaXFheXZ6ejkwMzdyZmxtNmUzcWFlbnNjIn0.IoKwNIJXoLuMHPuUXsXeug';
                var mapboxUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}';
                //var accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RhcnJtb3NzMSIsImEiOiJjam13ZHlxbXgwdncwM3FvMnJjeGVubjI5In0.-ridMV6bkkyNhbPfMJhVzw';
                var map = L.map('map').setView([37.7701177, -122.40], 13);
                    mapLink = 
                '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
                 L.tileLayer(
        'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/dark-v9/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + L.mapbox.accessToken, {
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

  // Read in the json data          
 d3.json("data/SanFrancisco_CoWorkingTenants.json", 
 function(SFData) {
     var SFData = SFCoworking.features
     console.log(SFData) // this prints successfully
    })


  var mapSVG = d3.select( "#map").select("svg")
  mapG = mapSVG.append("g");

   // Define d3 projection
   var albersProjectionBay = d3.geoAlbers()
        .scale( 282000)
        .rotate ( [122.4077441,] )
        .center( [0, 37.7701177] )

    // Define d3 path
    var geoPathBayArea = d3.geoPath()
        .projection( albersProjectionBay );


   var SFData = SFCoworking.features
       console.log(SFData)

    // draw points on map with d3 path generator 
    var feature = mapG.selectAll("path")
            .data(SFCoworking.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .style("stroke", "black")  
            .style("opacity", .6) 
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("r", 20)
            .attr( "d", geoPathBayArea )
            console.log(feature) // nothing prints!

        }
```

While the SFdata appears in the console, the features, when printed to the console, just appear as an empty array.  This leads me to believe there might be an issue in how I'm appending the svg element to the map?

Comment: do you have your last code snippet **INSIDE** the json load callback where you do the `console.log(SFData)` in the 3rd snippet

Comment: rio - not sure i understand your question?

Comment: you show snippets but not how they connect to each other or if they are sub-snippets, if they are just sequential you will never see something on the map (async loading)

Comment: rio - thanks.  i've edited my question above so hopefully the code sequence is clearer.  This is the basic code and how it works together.

Comment: put all the stuff inside the d3.json callback

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks but still no luck.  It's failing somewhere in that last function where I create the features, since feature is still coming up an empty array.  Or, something must be wrong with this:  var mapSVG = d3.select( "#map").select("svg")
        console.log(mapSVG)
      mapG = mapSVG.append("g");

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all - this seemed to work.

```
        var svgLayer = L.svg();
            svgLayer.addTo(map);

            var svgMap = d3.select("#map").select("svg");
            var g = svgMap.select('g');

        d3.json("data/SanFrancisco_CoWorkingTenants.json", function(SFData) {
            var SFData = SFCoworking.features
            console.log(SFData)
            })
        SFData.forEach(function(d) {
            d.latLong = new L.LatLng(d.properties.Latitude,
                                    d.properties.Longitude);
            //console.log(d.LatLng)
        })
        var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(SFData)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("opacity", .4)
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("r", 20)
            .attr("class", 'features')
```